# Asp.net Assembly Dependency Report

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I am working on an asp.net web application project that has around 7 – 10 custom and commercial assemblies. When I publish to production I am looking for a tool that will generate a report that gives me list of assembly name, version, and maybe location (GAC or c:\app\library) for that project.   This report can then be distributed to team for reference.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) may help you.